# value not set in contact form 7 plugin of wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

i'm using contact form 7 plugin in wordpress,
i have generate text field like this:

```
 [textarea your-message 25x3 "<?php  print_r($_POST); ?>"]
```

i have to set value of input name which comes from another form with POST method. but it's not worked, instead of input tag, it displays `; ?>"]` there is any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery for this, something like

```
<?php $name = $_GET['name']; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var yourget = '<?php echo $name; ?>';
$('input[name="nameofyourfield"]').val(yourget);
)};
</script>
```

Comment: this will basically store the variable from php in jquery and then set it as value for your input field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that contact form 7 doesn't support php or js code in template. Try plugin [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/screenshots/), it hasn't been updated in over 2 years, but it works on latest WP version with latest version of Contact Form 7. [More details](http://www.featheredowl.com/auto-populate-contact-form-7-input-fields-with-url-parameter/) how to use plug in.